# Shared NFS folder is empty on Vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm working on a project and trying to setup the environment.  In the Vagrantfile there is:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: 'nfs'
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

I ssh into the box/guest, but can't see any of the files from the share. My /etc/exports looks okay:

```
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 1000 14948e9b-4304-4359-9e8e-674f4ae10415
/home/{my_username}/open 192.168.33.10(rw,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,fsid=743045029)
# VAGRANT-END: 1000 14948e9b-4304-4359-9e8e-674f4ae10415
```

My UID on the box/guest when I ssh is 500, but on the host is 1000.  I tried to add the following lines to my Vagrantfile to make it match up:

```
  config.nfs.map_uid = Process.uid   
  config.nfs.map_gid = Process.gid
```

But, still no luck.  The host is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the box is bento/Centos-6.7.  There are no error msgs during vagrant up.  But, it doesn't list the folder being synced:

```
[default] Mounting NFS shared folders...
{There should be some msg about the folders here right?}
[default] VM already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use `--provision` to force it
```

EDIT:  Here is the relevant info from debug:

```
INFO synced_folders: Synced Folder Implementation: nfs
INFO synced_folders:   - /vagrant: ./ => /vagrant
INFO synced_folders: Invoking synced folder prepare for: nfs
INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::PrepareNFSSettings:0x00000001b38818>
```

But, later, there is no mention of the folders:

```
INFO interface: info: Mounting NFS shared folders...
DEBUG ssh: Checking whether SSH is ready...
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
INFO ssh: SSH is ready!
INFO guest: Execute capability: mount_nfs_folder (redhat)
DEBUG guest: Searching for cap: mount_nfs_folder
```

Is there anything in particular I should be looking for?

Also, I did check if nfs is running:

```
service nfs-kernel-server status
```

and got:`nsfd running`

And `showmount -e` gives me:

```
/home/{My username}/open 192.168.33.10
```

So... if a run `ls -l /vagrant` on the guest I can see the shared files!  So, how do I access them?

Comment: You could see if Vagrant debug provides any additional info. Are there other shares? I.e., is it using the "default" share for that location already? Did you try sharing a different directory?

Comment: I did a debug, lots of stuff to look through there.  I did a search for NFS and posted what I got.  Nothing looks fishy.  I'm only sharing this.  Tried to share another volume just now and got the same results, no error msgs during vagrant up.

Comment: Seems like it should work - I assume you've tried restarting to clear any possible network/vpn issues? I'm using a similar share: `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant_data", type: "nfs"` and it works fine. (You could try removing your trailing slash.)

Comment: Yeah, I've rebooted several times.  There has to be a newbie mistake in there somewhere.  The build instructions are for a Mac, so there might also be something I might have to change somewhere.

Comment: All right, if I run 'ls -l /vagrant' I can see the files.  So, why can't I see them normally?

Comment: its confusing .. what do you mean "why can't I see them normally?" can you explain further ?

Comment: The files will not show up with simply ls in the directory.  I have to name the directory explicitly `ls -l /vagrant`